# Differences between `isdigit` and `std::isdigit`

Tags: c++, std

Here's the code to find whether a string contains only digits:

```cpp
#include <iostream> //see below
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s("123");
    std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isdigit);  //error!
}
```

But the code doesn't compile, with the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'all_of'
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Predicate'
all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
```

When I replace `std::isdigit` with `isdigit`, the code compiles without errors.

```cpp
#include <iostream> //see below
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s("123");
    std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), isdigit);  //OK
}
```

So what's the differences between `isdigit` and `std::isdigit`? I know that `isdigit` is inherited from the C header `ctype.h`, and that `std::isdigit` is a wrapper defined in C++ header `cctype`, so essentially they should be the same. Am I getting anything wrong?

I tried the above on both Apple `clang` and linux `g++`, and got similar errors.

What's more confusing, when I remove the `#include <iostream>` line on Apple `clang`, the code compiles again:

```cpp
// iostream not included
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s("123");
    std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isdigit);  //OK
}
```

But removing `#include <iostream>` doesn't work on `gcc`.

Since both `clang` and `gcc` generated the same error, it's unlikely to be a bug of compilers. Am I getting anything wrong here?

Comment: I don't think `std::isdigit` is specified as an *addressable* function.  Use Remy's answer to wrap it in a lambda (which is addressable).

Comment: @Eljay good point. I keep forgetting about that restriction. I have added that to my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, you are not allowed to take the address of most standard library functions:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction

> The behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer, reference (for free functions and static member functions) or pointer-to-member (for non-static member functions) to a standard library function or an instantiation of a standard library function template, unless it is designated an *addressable function*

`std::isdigit()` is not an *addressable* standard library function, so you can't use it directly as an algorithm predicate.

That begin said, even if you could pass `std::isdigit()` directly as a predicate, doing so would risk *undefined behavior*:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

> Like all other functions from `<cctype>`, the behavior of `std::isdigit` is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as `unsigned char` nor equal to `EOF`. To use these functions safely with plain `char`s (or `signed char`s), the argument should first be converted to `unsigned char`:
>
> ```cpp
> bool my_isdigit(char ch)
> {
>     return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
> }
> ```
>
> Similarly, they should not be directly used with standard algorithms when the iterator's value type is `char` or `signed char`. Instead, convert the value to `unsigned char` first:
>
> ```cpp
> int count_digits(const std::string& s)
> {
>     return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
>                       // static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isdigit)         // wrong
>                       // [](int c){ return std::isdigit(c); }           // wrong
>                       // [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }          // wrong
>                          [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c); } // correct
>                         );
> }
> ```

As such, since you need to convert each `char` to `unsigned char` and back, you should call `std::isdigit()` inside of a lambda that is used as the predicate for `std::all_of()`, eg:

```cpp
std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(),
  [](unsigned char ch){ return std::isdigit(ch); }
);
```